# index with additional information

Tags: indexing, makeindex, biography

for a book publication I need to create an index of all persons appearing in the text, along with some biographical information about them.
It should be formatted like

```
Personenregister

KAMMEL, Richard, Lic. Dr.                   310f., 347, 363, 420
born 20.12.1882 Munich, Germany, died 1.12.1957 Berlin, was a great actor and so on

KUMMEL, Michael, Lic. Dr.                   310f., 347, 363, 420
born 21.12.1882 Berlin, Germany, died 2.12.1957 Munich, was a great writer and so on
```

,where 310f., 347, 363, 420 are the pages the person appears in the text.
As I am creating multiple indices for the book, I am using the package [multind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multind?lang=en), which in turn needs multicol. I am using makeindex currently, maybe something can be done with texindy. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multind}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{#1\index{personen}{#1}}
\makeindex{personen}
\begin{document}
\p{Kammel, Richard, Lic. Dr.}
\p{Kummel, Michael, Lic. Dr.}
\newpage
\newpage
\p{Kammel, Richard, Lic. Dr.}
\p{Kummel, Michael, Lic. Dr.}
\newpage
\printindex{personen}{Personenregister}
\end{document}
```

It would be ideal for me if I could specify the biographical information somehow within the indexing command, something like

```
\p{Kammel, Richard, Lic. Dr.}{born 20.12.1882 Munich, Germany, died 1.12.1957 Berlin, was a great actor and so on}
```

but if that is not possible, any other solution is fine as well.
Thanks so much for the help, this is a little bit too complicated for me.

Comment: What about using package like [`glossaries-extra`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra)?

Comment: can you give me hint what to look for in the docs?

Comment: Start with http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/#glossaries

Comment: With `biblatex` is possible make automatically and index of authors, showing the pages where each is cited, the problem is only include additional information, but `biblatex` is very flexible,  may be is easily solved.

Comment: Interesting, but I want an index of persons mentioned in the text which is different from the list of cited authors.

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks, that helped, it was some fiddling involved as always

Answer (score 3):

Working solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\glsaddkey*% star version needed as default value needs expanding
{nn}% key
{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}nn}% default value
{\glsentrynn}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentrynn}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsnn}% command analogous to \glstext
{\Glsnn}% command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSnn}% command analogous to \GLStext

\glsaddkey*% star version needed as default value needs expanding
{fn}% key
{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}fn}% default value
{\glsentryfn}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentryfn}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsfn}% command analogous to \glstext
{\Glsfn}% command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSfn}% command analogous to \GLStext

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{person-glossary}

\newglossarystyle{urls}
{% based on list style
    \setglossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
        \glspostdescription \qquad\qquad##2%
        \\
        \glossentrydesc{##1}}
}

\newcommand*{\entryurl}[1]{%
    \glsdoifexists{#1}%
    {%
        \glsletentryfield{\thisurl}{#1}{useri}%
        \expandafter\url\expandafter{\thisurl}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\forglsentries{\thislabel}{\gls{\thislabel}. }
The URL associated with the entry \gls{abromeit}
is \entryurl{abromeit}.
\newpage
\newpage
\gls{abromeit}
\newpage
\newpage
\gls{abromeit}
\newpage
\newpage
\glsnn{abromeit}
\printglossary[style=urls,nopostdot=true,nogroupskip]

\end{document}
```

with person-glossary.tex:

```
\newglossaryentry{abromeit} {
    name = {Abromeit, Hans - Jürgen}, nn = {Abromeit},
    fn = {Hans - Jürgen Abromeit}, description = {
        geb. 13.10.1954 Gevelsberg(Westfalen),
        seit 2001 Bischof der PEK,
        seit Pfingsten 2012 Bischof im Sprengel Mecklenburg und Pommern.
    }
}
```